# Bounty allocated amount looks odd

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounty

When a bounty is allocated to an answer, the bounty amount is shown against it. This kind of looks weird in Ask Ubuntu

[image: bounty allocated AU]

In contrast, the bounty allocated amount in Super User is much.. better

[image]

Comment: I agree it's too big. I'll fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it is a little funky compared to the Super User screenshot.

However I think that's part of our site's character, and it's good for bounties to stand out.